# What do 'lazy' and 'greedy' mean in the context of regular expressions?

Tags: regex, regex-greedy, non-greedy

What are these two terms in an understandable way?

Comment: See also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3075130/difference-between-and-for-regex/3075532#3075532

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Greedy vs. Reluctant vs. Possessive Qualifiers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5319840/greedy-vs-reluctant-vs-possessive-qualifiers)

Answer (score 947, accepted):

Greedy will consume as much as possible. From http://www.regular-expressions.info/repeat.html we see the example of trying to match HTML tags with `<.+>`. Suppose you have the following:

```
<em>Hello World</em>
```

You may think that `<.+>` (`.` means *any non newline character* and `+` means *one or more*) would only match the `<em>` and the `</em>`, when in reality it will be very greedy, and go from the first `<` to the last `>`. This means it will match `<em>Hello World</em>` instead of what you wanted.

Making it lazy (`<.+?>`) will prevent this. By adding the `?` after the `+`, we tell it to repeat *as few times as possible*, so the first `>` it comes across, is where we want to stop the matching.

I'd encourage you to download [RegExr](http://www.gskinner.com/RegExr/), a great tool that will help you explore Regular Expressions - I use it all the time.

Comment: so if you use greedy will u have 3 (1 element + 2 tags) matches or just 1 match (1 element)?

Comment: It would match only 1 time, starting from the first **<** and ending with the last **>**.

Comment: But making it lazy would match twice, giving us both the opening and closing tag, ignoring the text in between (since it doesn't fit the expression).

Comment: Another great tool I always use: https://www.debuggex.com/ It also has a "Embed on StackOverflow" function.

Comment: Just to add that there is a greedy way to go about it, too:
`<[^>]+>`
https://regex101.com/r/lW0cY6/1

Comment: In case one wants to delve a bit deeper into how lazy and greedy quantifiers work with optional subpatterns in-between them, check [*Perl regex matching optional phrase in longer sentence*](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36770799/perl-regex-matching-optional-phrase-in-longer-sentence/36787675#36787675).

Comment: For the record, about using regex with HTML https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags

Comment: It's curious, no more, that the highest-voted and selected answer is one that gives an example of a regex being used to parse HTML, even though it is generally recommended that an HTML parser be used for that task. A criticism, however, is that no definitions of the two concepts are given, only the results for an example. The first sentence, in particular, is so vague as to be meaningless.

Answer (score 461):

**'Greedy'** means match longest possible string.

**'Lazy'** means match shortest possible string.

For example, the greedy `h.+l` matches `'hell'` in `'hello'` but the lazy `h.+?l` matches `'hel'`.

Comment: Brilliant, so  lazy will stop as soon as the condition l is satisfied, but greedy means it will stop only once the condition l is not satisfied any more?

Comment: For all people reading the post: greedy or lazy quantifiers by themselves won't match the longest/shortest possible substring. You would have to use either a [**tempered greedy token**](http://www.rexegg.com/regex-quantifiers.html#tempered_greed), or use non-regex approaches.

Comment: @AndrewS Don't be confused by the double ll in the example. It's rather lazy will match the shortest possible substring while greedy will match the longest possible. Greedy `h.+l` matches `'helol'` in `'helolo'` but the lazy `h.+?l` matches `'hel'`.

Comment: Doesn't the `?` make the `.+` optional in `h.+?l`. Isn't that what the `?` is for? Also, how would you differentiate between the two functions of `?`

Comment: @FloatingRock: No. `x?` means `x` is optional but `+?` is a different syntax. It means stop looking after you find something that matches - lazy matching.

Comment: @FloatingRock: As for how you differentiate the different syntax, simple: `?` means optional and `+?` means lazy. Therefore `\+?` means `+` is optional.

Answer (score 291):

| Greedy quantifier | Lazy quantifier | Description |
| --- | --- | --- |
| `*` | `*?` | Star Quantifier: 0 or more |
| `+` | `+?` | Plus Quantifier: 1 or more |
| `?` | `??` | Optional Quantifier: 0 or 1 |
| `{n}` | `{n}?` | Quantifier: exactly n |
| `{n,}` | `{n,}?` | Quantifier: n or more |
| `{n,m}` | `{n,m}?` | Quantifier: between n and m |

> Add a ? to a quantifier to make it ungreedy i.e lazy.

**Example:**
test string : *stackoverflow*
*greedy reg expression* : [`s.*o`](http://regexr.com/3glo4) output: **stackoverflo**w
*lazy reg expression* : [`s.*?o`](http://regexr.com/3glo7) output: **stacko**verflow

Comment: is not ?? equivalent to ? . Similarly , isn't {n}? equivalen to {n}

Comment: @BreakingBenjamin: no ?? is not equivalent to ?, when it has a choice to either return 0 or 1 occurrence, it will pick the 0 (lazy) alternative. To see the difference, compare `re.match('(f)?(.*)', 'food').groups()` to `re.match('(f)??(.*)', 'food').groups()`. In the latter, `(f)??` will not match the leading 'f' even though it could. Hence the 'f' will get matched by the second '.*' capture group. I'm sure you can construct an example with '{n}?' too. Admittedly these two are very-rarely-used.

Comment: @Number945 Yes, `{n}?` is equivalent to `{n}`. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18006093/how-do-an-and-an-differ

Answer (score 76):

Greedy means your expression will match as large a group as possible, lazy means it will match the smallest group possible.  For this string:

```
abcdefghijklmc
```

and this expression:

```
a.*c
```

A greedy match will match the whole string, and a lazy match will match just the first `abc`.

Comment: For anyone else wondering, the expression mentioned above, `a.*c`, is greedy, while `a.*?c` would be the lazy counterpart.

Answer (score 28):

As far as I know, most regex engine is greedy by default. Add a question mark at the end of quantifier will enable lazy match.

As @Andre S mentioned in comment.

- Greedy: Keep searching until condition is not satisfied.
- Lazy: Stop searching once condition is satisfied.

Refer to the example below for what is greedy and what is lazy.

```
import java.util.regex.Matcher;
import java.util.regex.Pattern;

public class Test {
    public static void main(String args[]){
        String money = "100000000999";
        String greedyRegex = "100(0*)";
        Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile(greedyRegex);
        Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(money);
        while(matcher.find()){
            System.out.println("I'm greedy and I want " + matcher.group() + " dollars. This is the most I can get.");
        }
        
        String lazyRegex = "100(0*?)";
        pattern = Pattern.compile(lazyRegex);
        matcher = pattern.matcher(money);
        while(matcher.find()){
            System.out.println("I'm too lazy to get so much money, only " + matcher.group() + " dollars is enough for me");
        }
    }
}
```

---

The result is:

```
I'm greedy and I want 100000000 dollars. This is the most I can get.

I'm too lazy to get so much money, only 100 dollars is enough for me
```

Answer (score 24):

Taken From [www.regular-expressions.info](http://www.regular-expressions.info/possessive.html)

**Greediness**: Greedy quantifiers first tries to repeat the token as many times
as possible, and gradually gives up matches as the engine backtracks to find 
an overall match.

**Laziness**: Lazy quantifier first repeats the token as few times as required, and
gradually expands the match as the engine backtracks through the regex to
find an overall match.

Comment: This seems to be the most correct definition of "Laziness" compared with the higher-voted answers.  The other answers seem to omit the concept that under laziness the engine "gradually expands the match...to find an overall match".

Answer (score 10):

From [Regular expression](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regular_expression)

> The standard quantifiers in regular
>   expressions are greedy, meaning they
>   match as much as they can, only giving
>   back as necessary to match the
>   remainder of the regex.
>
> By using a lazy quantifier, the
>   expression tries the minimal match
>   first.

Answer (score 10):

**Greedy matching.** The default behavior of regular expressions is to be greedy. That means it tries to extract as much as possible until it conforms to a pattern even when a smaller part would have been syntactically sufficient.

**Example:**

```
import re
text = "<body>Regex Greedy Matching Example </body>"
re.findall('<.*>', text)
#> ['<body>Regex Greedy Matching Example </body>']
```

Instead of matching till the first occurrence of ‘>’, it extracted the whole string. This is the default greedy or ‘take it all’ behavior of regex.

**Lazy matching**, on the other hand, ‘takes as little as possible’. This can be effected by adding a `?` at the end of the pattern.

**Example:**

```
re.findall('<.*?>', text)
#> ['<body>', '</body>']
```

If you want only the first match to be retrieved, use the search method instead.

```
re.search('<.*?>', text).group()
#> '<body>'
```

Source: [Python Regex Examples](https://www.machinelearningplus.com/python-regex-tutorial-examples/#greedy_matching_in_regex)

Answer (score 8):

### Greedy Quantifiers are like the IRS

They’ll take as much as they can. e.g. matches with this regex: `.*`

`$50,000`

Bye-bye bank balance.

See here for an example: [Greedy-example](https://regexr.com/4t27f)

### Non-greedy quantifiers - they take as little as they can

Ask for a tax refund: the IRS sudden becomes non-greedy - and return as little as possible: i.e. they use this quantifier:

`(.{2,5}?)([0-9]*)` against this input: `$50,000`

The first group is non-needy and only matches `$5` – so I get a `$5` refund against the $50,000 input.

See here: [Non-greedy-example](https://regexr.com/59qrk).

### Why do we need greedy vs non-greedy?

It becomes important if you are trying to match certain parts of an expression. Sometimes you don't want to match everything - as little as possible. Sometimes you want to match as much as possible. Nothing more to it.

You can play around with the examples in the links posted above.

(Analogy used to help you remember).

Answer (score 6):

Best shown by example. String. `192.168.1.1` and a greedy regex `\b.+\b`
You might think this would give you the 1st octet but is actually matches against the whole string. Why? Because the.+ is greedy and a greedy match matches every character in `192.168.1.1` until it reaches the end of the string. This is the important bit! Now it starts to backtrack one character at a time until it finds a match for the 3rd token (`\b`).

If the string a 4GB text file and 192.168.1.1 was at the start you could easily see how this backtracking would cause an issue.

To make a regex non greedy (lazy) put a question mark after your greedy search e.g

```
*?
??
+?
```

What happens now is token 2 (`+?`) finds a match, regex moves along a character and then tries the next token (`\b`) rather than token 2 (`+?`). So it creeps along gingerly.

Answer (score 5):

Greedy means it will consume your pattern until there are none of them left and it can look no further.

Lazy will stop as soon as it will encounter the first pattern you requested.

One common example that I often encounter is `\s*-\s*?` of a regex `([0-9]{2}\s*-\s*?[0-9]{7})`

The first `\s*` is classified as greedy because of `*` and will look as many white spaces as possible after the digits are encountered and then look for a dash character "-". Where as the second `\s*?` is lazy because of the present of `*?` which means that it will look the first white space character and stop right there.

Comment: I don't understand how that regex is any different from not using a lazy quantifier. `\s` can only match a white space and there's a requirement for 7 digits after it.

Answer (score 0):

To give extra clarification on Laziness, here is one example which is maybe not intuitive on first look but explains idea of "gradually expands the match" from Suganthan Madhavan Pillai answer.

```
input -> some.email@domain.com@
regex -> ^.*?@$
```

Regex for this input will have a match. At first glance somebody could say LAZY match(".*?@") will stop at first @ after which it will check that input string ends("$"). Following this logic someone would conclude there is no match because input string doesn't end after first @.

But as you can see this is not the case, regex will go forward even though we are using non-greedy(lazy mode) search until it hits second @ and have a MINIMAL match.

Answer (score -3):

try to understand the following behavior:

```
    var input = "0014.2";

Regex r1 = new Regex("\\d+.{0,1}\\d+");
Regex r2 = new Regex("\\d*.{0,1}\\d*");

Console.WriteLine(r1.Match(input).Value); // "0014.2"
Console.WriteLine(r2.Match(input).Value); // "0014.2"

input = " 0014.2";

Console.WriteLine(r1.Match(input).Value); // "0014.2"
Console.WriteLine(r2.Match(input).Value); // " 0014"

input = "  0014.2";

Console.WriteLine(r1.Match(input).Value); // "0014.2"
Console.WriteLine(r2.Match(input).Value); // ""
```

Comment: What language is this?

Comment: The language he used is C#